# view and share media from debian on a mobile

Tags: mobile, media-manager

There is a few terabytes of media, predominantly pictures, on a debian device. They can be accessed with smb (samba) or ssh (sftp, sshfs). I would like to be able to view these media items on Android and iOS and share them by email, Skype, WhatsApp, and GNU Jami.

I tried Kodi and it is a good viewer, but does not have a share button.

Looking for libre solutions ONLY, such as those from f-droid. I just couldn't find a suitable app there. I wouldn't want proprietary mobile apps to have access to my computer.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Afraid you're right, I've just checked and found no suitable gallery or file explorer app at F-Droid (or in my repo). But speaking Debian, there might be another option: there's MiniDLNA available via the Debian repos, which provides a very simple DLNA server (works fine, I'm using that myself). Then you could use a DLNA client to browse that server. [DMS Explorer](https://apt.izzysoft.de/fdroid/index/apk/net.mm2d.dmsexplorer) might be able to do that, or [Yaacc](https://f-droid.org/packages/de.yaacc/) – I haven't tried them yet though.

Comment: @Izzy thank you, DLNA works well. :-) Regards,

Comment: Glad to read! I expanded my comment to an answer you can find below. If you mark that as "accepted" (i.e. tick the "check mark" next to it), it will show other users this solution worked for you. Thanks!

Comment: @Izzy Thanks - follow up question about this at https://superuser.com/questions/1560614/show-and-cache-thumbnails-in-dlna-client

Comment: Ah, OK – so it's YAACC you decided for. I'd then approach their devs for the caching question; just raise an issue in their tracker (after having checked nobody else already did).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afraid you're right, I've just checked and found no suitable gallery or file explorer app at F-Droid (or in my repo).

But speaking Debian, there might be another option: there's **[MiniDLNA](https://wiki.debian.org/minidlna)** available via the Debian repos, which provides a very simple DLNA server (works fine, I'm using that myself). Then you could use a DLNA client to browse that server. Two free and open-source apps might help you on the Android end:

- **[DMS Explorer](https://apt.izzysoft.de/fdroid/index/apk/net.mm2d.dmsexplorer)** is available in my own F-Droid repo (which you can add from inside the F-Droid client, instructions on its main page)
- **[Yaacc](https://f-droid.org/packages/de.yaacc/)** is available in F-Droid's own repo

I haven't tried any of them yet though – but as you report in your comment on the question, at least one of them seems to do the job for you (be welcome to point out in a comment which one it is). *DMS Explorer* seems also capable of acting as "control point" – so if you have e.g. a TV capable to act as receiver, you can use it to "beam" the pictures from your Debian machine there, using the app as "remote control".